# ccxt crypto API - Does it support OAuth access tokens?

Tags: node.js, cryptoapi, ccxt

The API for ccxt.coinbase accepts API keys and secrets. How do I pass it an accessToken? That attribute does not seem to be valid.

All examples I see in the documentation (https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual) use API keys and I have not found an OAuth2 example.

I have a mobile wallet app where I want to give my users the ability to keep track of their Coinbase wallets all in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the [source code for ccxt.coinbase](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/ccxt/async_support/coinbase.py), there doesn't seem to be any support for passing along tokens. Although there is support for token error handling.

Do you have non-ccxt code that makes this possible? Maybe you could adopt it so that it can be added to the ccxt repo.